# It can't be able to run the Laravel index file it show an error message 404 not found

Tags: laravel

i am not able to run the file in localhost using laravel framework and index page is there in public folder.......  but can't be able to run the file checked for apache it's running
 path : var/www/html/laravel/public/index.php

Install apache2 and laravel of ngnix,installed success and can't be able to run index file in public folder so i am stuck here only

Answer (score 1):

try going into the root of your laravel project, and run: `php artisan serv` in a console/terminal.